# Trying to get all input value into string, jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery or javascript get all input value into a string (1,2,3,4) and ignore empty value. Thank you.

```html
<form id="sym_form">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_1" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_2" value="2">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_3" value="3">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_4" value="4">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_5" value="">

   </form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where is the jQuery/Javascript to go with this? What problem(s) are you having with your current attempt(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // string to keep the result
  var output = "";
  // iterate over all inputs with class 'as_sym' inside the '#sym_form'
  $('#sym_form > input[class=as_sym]').each(function(){
    // only inputs with non-empty values                                                                                                        
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      // the first value doesn't have a comma in front of it
      // subsequent values do have a comma in front of them
      if (output == "") {
        output += $(this).val();
      } else {
        output += "," + $(this).val();
      }
    }
  });
  // here do whatever you want with the 'output' variable
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
const form = document.getELementById("sym_form");
for (var element of form.elements) {
    if(element.nodeName === "INPUT" && element.value) {
        // do something with element.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $inputs = $('#sym_form .as_sym');
var result ="";

$.each($inputs, function(i, v) {
   var val = $(this).val();
   result += val;
  });

$('#result').text(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="sym_form">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_1" value="1">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_2" value="2">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_3" value="3">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_4" value="4">
    <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_5" value="">

   </form>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` to select all `"#sym_form .as_sym"` elements, `Array.prototype.forEach()`, `Function.prototype.call()` to attach `input` event to each element, at `input` event concantenate values of each `"#sym_form .as_sym"` element to a string, use `.split()`, `.join()` to include comma `,` character between each character or resulting string

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#sym_form .as_sym");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    for (var i = 0, val = "", len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
      val += inputs[i].value;
    }
    console.log(val.split("").join(","))
  })
})
```

```html
<form id="sym_form">
  <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_1" value="1">
  <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_2" value="2">
  <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_3" value="3">
  <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_4" value="4">
  <input type="text" class="as_sym" id="sym_5" value="">

</form>
```